# How to effectively search documentation about JavaScript(NodeJS) object types?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please explain me how to read this NodeJS docs [fs.readFile(file[, options], callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback)

> data is the contents of the file.

What is the "contents"?!

In strongly typed language like C++ or Java when I need to get know info about some method argument or return value e.g. [System.getProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) which has argument named `key` and its type (as we can **really easily** see from the method signature) is String.

1. I open a class (in our case it's `System`) in JDK documentation and scroll to a method I interested in.
2. If I need to know what can I do with the argument or return value (I mean what the methods the argument has and etc.) I simply click on the class `String` and goto step 1.

So, **my question:** I'm writing

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.???
  // is  data.replace(/abc/g, 'xyz') OK? what else???

});
```

How can I determine the type(do I need the type?) of the data object (first of all I need the list of methods)?

How I supposed to know that the `data` is probably `String` consequently it has method `replace`?

PS: Obviously helpless `console.log(typeof data);` says it is just an `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not as good as the JavaDocs.  If you read through a bit you'll find what you are looking for.  They don't have links set up for the return object - I think they should since they have it for the function arguments.

From the docs:

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer

> If options is a string, then it specifies the encoding.

Then further down:

> If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a string. Otherwise it returns a buffer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type

To answer your question:  You know it a string because you specified an encoding.  If you never you would have a buffer.

When I called 'type of' on my result it returned a String or an Object for Buffer.

Here is some output:

```
    fs.readFile('c:\\test.txt','utf-8',function (err,data) {  
    console.log(data); }
    );
```

> ��T e s t
>   T e x t
>   H e l l o
>   W o r l d !

```
fs.readFile('c:\\test.txt',null,function (err,data) {  
console.log(data); 
});
```

> Buffer ff fe 54 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 0d 00 0a 00 54 00 65 00 78 00 74 00 0d 0
>   0 0a 00 48 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00 0d 00 0a 00 57 00 6f 00 72 00 6c 00 64 00
>   ...

```
 fs.readFile('c:\\test.txt','utf-8',function (err,data) { 
 console.log(typeof data); 
});
```

> string

```
 fs.readFile('c:\\test.txt',null,function (err,data) {  
  console.log(typeof data);  });
```

> object

You can also use instanceof:

```
 fs.readFile('c:\\test.txt',null,function (err,data) {  
console.log(data instanceof Buffer); 
});
```

> true